# How to create a global modal to show message when needed in any component in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to create a global component to show error message or info message in Vue 3, like Alert or Comfirm Modal.

In Vue2, I can do this, create a `plugin` like this:

```js
import AlertComponent from "./Alert.vue";

const Alert = {};

Alert.install = (Vue) => {
    const AlertConstructor = Vue.extend(AlertComponent);
    const instance = new AlertConstructor();
    instance.$mount(document.createElement("div"));

    Vue.prototype.$alert = (msg) => {
        document.body.appendChild(instance.$el);
        // alert logic
        instance.type = "alert";
        instance.msg = msg;
        instance.isShow = true;
        instance.instance = instance;
    };

    Vue.prototype.$confirm = (msg, success, cancel) => {
        document.body.appendChild(instance.$el);
        // confirm logic
        instance.type = "confirm";
        instance.msg = msg;
        instance.isShow = true;
        instance.instance = instance;
        if (typeof success !== "undefined") {
            instance.success = success;
        }
        if (typeof cancel !== "undefined") {
            instance.cancel = cancel;
        }
    };
};

export default Alert;
```

which I can import it in `main.js`:

```js
import Alert from './components/modules/alert'

Vue.use(Alert)
```

And use it in any component like this:

```js
this.$alert('xxxxx message')

// or

this.$confirm('xxxx', () => {})
```

Question:

How to create a such function/component in Vue3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `createApp` to render the component in Vue 3:

```js
// components/modules/alert/alert.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import AlertComponent from './Alert.vue'

const Alert = {}

Alert.install = (app) => {
  const instance = createApp(AlertComponent).mount(document.createElement('div'))

  app.config.globalProperties.$alert = (msg) => {
    document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    // alert logic
    instance.type = 'alert'
    instance.msg = msg
    instance.isShow = true
    instance.instance = instance
  }

  app.config.globalProperties.$confirm = (msg, success, cancel) => {
    document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    // confirm logic
    instance.type = 'confirm'
    instance.msg = msg
    instance.isShow = true
    instance.instance = instance
    if (typeof success !== 'undefined') {
      instance.success = success
    }
    if (typeof cancel !== 'undefined') {
      instance.cancel = cancel
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// main.js
import Alert from './components/modules/alert'
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(Alert);
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track but it should be `export const Alert = {}` at the top

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x the app instance is created trough `createApp` so you don't need `Vue` constructor:

```js
import AlertComponent from './Alert.vue'

export const Alert = {}

Alert.install = (app) => {
  const AlertConstructor ={extend:AlertComponent}
  const instance = new AlertConstructor()
  instance.$mount(document.createElement('div'))

  app.config.globalProperties.$alert = (msg) => {
    document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    // alert logic
    instance.type = 'alert'
    instance.msg = msg
    instance.isShow = true
    instance.instance = instance
  }

  app.config.globalProperties.$confirm = (msg, success, cancel) => {
    document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    // confirm logic
    instance.type = 'confirm'
    instance.msg = msg
    instance.isShow = true
    instance.instance = instance
    if (typeof success !== 'undefined') {
      instance.success = success
    }
    if (typeof cancel !== 'undefined') {
      instance.cancel = cancel
    }
  }
}
```

then import it in `main.js` like :

```
import Alert from './components/modules/alert'
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(Alert);
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer, I tried, got 'Uncaught TypeError: app.extend is not a function'

Comment: Try out `const AlertConstructor ={extend:AlertComponent}` instead of `const AlertConstructor = app.extend(AlertComponent)`

Comment: here's the code: https://github.com/kanlidy/Vue3-demo/blob/master/src/components/modules/alert/index.ts, not working, thx

Comment: I also tried your second advice, still not working.

Comment: `export default Alert` for Vue3 is incorrect, it should be  `export const Alert = {}` at the top