# Vue3 Plugin giving error 'does not provide an export named 'default'' - how do I export it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I haven't tried creating a Vue plugin before and I am trying to follow the code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965309) (the accepted answer).
So I have created an 'alert.js':

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import AlertComponent from './Alert.vue'

const Alert = {}

Alert.install = (app) => {
  const instance = createApp(AlertComponent).mount(document.createElement('div'))

  app.config.globalProperties.$myAlert = (msg) => {
    document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
    // alert logic
    instance.type = 'alert'
    instance.msg = msg
    instance.isShow = true
    instance.instance = instance
  }
}
```

and in `main.ts` I have

```
....
import { Alert } from './components/alert.js'
....
createApp(App).use(Alert).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

my alert.vue (so far) is this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  type: String,
  msg: String,
  title: String
})
</script>

<v-alert
    closable
    type=type
    title=title
    text=msg
></v-alert>
```

which probably isn't correct yet, but I can't get as far as debugging it because I get a error message from 'main.ts`

> The requested module '/src/components/alert.js?t=1691582652693' does not provide an export named 'default'

I have tried adding `export default Alert;` to the end of the file but that's only for vue2. I have also tried adding `export` to `const Alert = {}` at the top, but that hasn't helped.

I have looked elsewhere for how to solve this; answers generally suggest the curly brackets around the import, which I have done.

Comment: The error "does not provide an export named 'Alert'" means what it says. There's no Alert export. You incorrectly copied code from linked post. The question is contradictory. It says "default" in another place

Comment: Yes I'm sure it means what it says. But how do I export it? The line `export default Alert` which I magine you refer to when you say I copied incorrectly, is part of the vue2 version in the question, not the vue3 version in the answer.

Comment: It exists in the answer. You didn't scroll the snippet. It doesn't matter which framework you use, the code is still JS. If you import something that you didn't export, this will result in an error

Comment: Yes it exists in the _second_ answer (the non-accepted one). But it gives the error I mentioned. Anyway, solved it now, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of `alert.js` I have changed

```
const Alert = {}
```

to

```
export const Alert = {}
```

I had tried this before posting my question, but it didn't make any difference to start with. I have now found that it is necessary to stop the Vite server, and re-start it, to update a plugin  - it doesn't hot reload! Of course.